# TERADATA MAX criteria not resulting in expected number of rows

Tags: sql, max, teradata

Good afternoon all, I'm at a bit of a roadblock with what exactly is going on with my MAX here. Instead of returning the expected 1 to 1 per every unique EQUIPMENT and PM relationship row, where the WORKORDER has the most recent COMPLETEDDATE. However, what i'm getting back as an output is every related WORKORDER per unique EQUIPMENT-PM that has occurred.
Example:

```
CURRENT RESULTS
EQUIPMENT  |  PM   |  WORKORDER   |  COMPLETEDDATE  |
ALPHA-WL   |    P1 |    DS1234    |    7/9/2020
ALPHA-WL   |    P1 |    DS1233    |    6/3/2020
ALPHA-WL   |    P2 |    DS1532    |    7/9/2020
BETA-WL    |    P2 |    DS4321    |    4/2/2020
BETA-WL    |    P2 |    DS4331    |    5/2/2020

EXPECTED RESULTS
EQUIPMENT  |   PM  |  WORKORDER  |  COMPLETEDDATE  | 
ALPHA-WL   |   P1  |   DS1234    |   7/9/2020
ALPHA-WL   |   P2  |  DS1532     |   7/9/2020
BETA-WL    |   P2  |  DS4331     |   5/2/2020
```

I thought maybe it was an issue with the format of the date in COMPLETEDDATE so I went ahead and casted it to something that should work, however that still didn't resolve the issue. I would really appreciate any support I could get on this matter, here is an example of the SQL being used.

```
SELECT  
MRC,
EQUIPMENT,
DESCRIPTION,
CLASSCODE,
CRITICALITY,
STATUS,
PM,
PMDESCRIPTION,
NEXTDUE,
PMTYPE,
ASSIGNEDBY,
ASSIGNEDTO,
FREQUENCY,
UOM,
WOEQUIP,
WORKORDER,
WORKORDERPM,
PMCHECKS,
EQCHECKS,
MAX(LastCompleted) AS COMPLETEDDATE,
WOSTATUS
FROM
(SELECT
SE.EquipmentSurfaceAssetBK AS "MRC",
SE.EquipmentCodeBK AS "EQUIPMENT",
SE.EquipmentDescription AS "DESCRIPTION",
SE.EquipmentClassBK AS "CLASSCODE",
SE.EquipmentCriticality AS "CRITICALITY",
SE.EquipmentCostCode AS "COSTCODE",
SE.EquipmentStatus AS "STATUS",
PE.EqPMCodeBK AS "PM",
PM.PMDescription AS "PMDESCRIPTION",
PE.EqPMDueDate AS "NEXTDUE",
PE.EqPMType AS "PMTYPE",
PE.EqPMDeactivatedDate AS "DDATE",
PE.EqPMAssignedBy AS "ASSIGNEDBY",
PE.EqPMAssignedToResourceBK AS "ASSIGNEDTO",
PE.EqPMFrequency AS "FREQUENCY",
PE.EqPMFrequencyUOM AS "UOM",
WO.WorkOrderEquipmentcodeBK AS "WOEQUIP",
WO.WorkOrderCodeBK AS "WORKORDER",
WO.WorkOrderPMCodeBK AS "WORKORDERPM",
CASE
    WHEN WO.WorkOrderPMCodeBK = PE.EqPMCodeBK THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO'
END AS "PMCHECKS",
CASE
    WHEN WO.WorkOrderEquipmentcodeBK = SE.EquipmentCodeBK THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO'
END AS "EQCHECKS",
WO.WorkOrderStatus AS "WOSTATUS",
CAST( CAST(WO.WorkOrderCompletedDate AS DATE FORMAT 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS DATE FORMAT 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS "LastCompleted"
FROM IDW_PL_SURFACE.DIMSurfaceEquipment SE 
JOIN IDW_PL_SURFACE.DIMEquipmentPM PE ON SE.EquipmentCodeBK = PE.EqPMEquipmentCodeBK
JOIN IDW_PL_SURFACE.DIMSurfacePM PM ON PE.EqPMCodeBK = PM.PMCodeBK
JOIN IDW_PL_SURFACE.DIMWorkOrder WO ON SE.EquipmentCodeBK = WO.WorkOrderEquipmentcodeBK) AS ST
WHERE 
1=1
AND
STATUS IN ( 'I', 'IDLE')
AND
DDATE is Null
AND
PMTYPE IN (  'V', 'F')
AND PMCHECKS IN ( 'YES')
AND EQCHECKS IN ( 'YES')
AND WOSTATUS IN ('C', 'D')
AND NEXTDUE IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
MRC,
EQUIPMENT,
DESCRIPTION,
CLASSCODE,
CRITICALITY,
STATUS,
PM,
PMDESCRIPTION,
NEXTDUE,
PMTYPE,
ASSIGNEDBY,
ASSIGNEDTO,
FREQUENCY,
UOM,
WOEQUIP,
WORKORDER,
WORKORDERPM,
PMCHECKS,
EQCHECKS,
WOSTATUS
```

Comment: If what you want is the source row with most recent date, then you don't want regular aggregation, you want to filter based on a windowed aggregate, something like `QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Equipment, PM ORDER BY CompletedDate DESC) = 1`

Comment: Thanks, I was previously using RANK as my qualifier and it pulled the initial record. using ROW_NUMBER pulled the last. appreciate the assistance.